# xpath: how to convert following xml into resulting data format?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

EXAMPLE 1:

```
<body>
    <div>
    <h1>category1</h1><a>sibling1</a><a>sibling2</a><h1>category2</h1><a>sibling3</a><a>sibling4</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

so they don't have a common ancestor other than that they are under the single div. How would you be able to produce (that can be expressed by an xpath) the following resulting string data format?

```
category1,sibling1,sibling2;
category2,sibling3,sibling4;
```

if EXAMPLE 1 was something like this:

```
    <body>
        <div>
<span>
        <h1>category1</h1><a>sibling1</a><a>sibling2</a>
</span>
<span>
        <h1>category2</h1><a>sibling3</a><a>sibling4</a>
</span>
        </div>
    </body>
```

here in this case, it's quite easy, all that is required is to capture all `<SPAN>` tags via `//span` xpath expression and look insde each `<span>` tags for it's `<h1>` & `<a>` inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all `h1` using `//h1`, then select two siblings of h1, i.e.: `following-sibling::*[position() < 3]`

Answer (score 1):

The resulting string is hard to achieve in XPath 1.0, because of missing a `string-join()` function present in XPath 2.0.

In general if you can iterate on each h1 node, you can use the following xpath to select all texts of the adjacent siblings before next h1 (e.g. for first h1):

```
"/html/body/div/h1[1]//text()
|
/html/body/div/h1[1]/following-sibling::*
[count( . | following-sibling::h1[1]/preceding-sibling::* )
 = count( following-sibling::h1[1]/preceding-sibling::* )]//text()"
```

For last h1 node the path is much simple:

```
"/html/body/div/h1[last()]//text()
|
/html/body/div/h1[last()]/following-sibling::*//text()"
```

In XPath 2.0 you can concatenate strings directly as follows:

```
string-join(xpath,',')
```

where you can xpath as above.